# How to pass dictionary argument in functions in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.7

I have recently started learning Python 3.7 but I am following Python 2.7 for learning purposes. The query is how can we pass the dictionary argument in function?

This is what we get result in python 2.7 when I execute below code :-

```
def param(first, last, *age, **items):
print first, last
print age
print items
```

Output -

```
param('katy', 'dhilon', 23,45,23,12,67, baron=5, sausage=64)

katy dhilon
(23, 45, 23, 12, 67)
{'baron' = 5, 'sausage' = 64}
```

But, when I execute the same in python 3.7 :-

```
param('katy', 'dhilon', 23,45,23,12,67, baron=5, sausage=64)
```

I am getting error for the dictionary argument as :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'param' is not defined
```

Could you please help me to understand what I missing as a part of new releases?

Added python 2.7 result :-

[image]

Comment: Well, apparently, you didn't define the `param` function in your Python 3 code. Please show the exact code you're running in Python 3

Comment: thanks for reply.. i have edited the question. may be i am missing some concept here. please guide me.. i am new to this.

Comment: Does your Python 3 code consist _only_ of this line: `param('katy', 'dhilon', 23,45,23,12,67, baron=5, sausage=64) `?

Comment: def param(first, last, *age, **items):
print first, last
print age
print items  and yes and it works in python 2.7 but not in 3.7. is the code correct for 3.7.? i mean can i use the same code for 3.7 also?

Comment: No, it doesn't: open a new Python 2 interpreter and try to run this one line. You'll get the same error. This is because the name `param` doesn't refer to anything when you use just this one line. You need to define the function before calling it

Comment: This code is not correct in Python 3 because [the syntax of the `print` statement changed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/), but your error message tells you that you didn't define the `param` function

Comment: yes.. i have added the result for python 2.7.. could you pleae tell me the code for python 3.7? what is wrong here..

Comment: Could you please add the _Python 3_ result? The full code you're running and its output

Comment: hey.. thanks.. I was missing the parenthesis for the print statement.. it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.7.. As commented by @ForceBru that print statement is changed so, here is the updated code : -

```
def param(first, last, *age, **items):
    print (first, last)
    print (age)
    print (items)
```

Output -

```
param('nicky', 'rana', 34, 38, 56, 12, 23, baron=9, nio=10)

nicky rana
(34, 38, 56, 12, 23)
{'baron': 9, 'nio': 10}
```